# Change value of a variable in JSP

Tags: jsp

I am fairly new to JSP , i learned that to create a variable you say this

```
<%String abc="1"; %>
```

If i want to change to value of abc I used this

```
<%= abc = "2" %> //Is this the right way??
```

But this value is shown on my JSP page how do I make it not show in my jsp page.

Comment: I encourage you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer to your question is remove the `=`.  The `<%= %>` evaluates and prints the contents.  Anything between `<% %>` is just standard java code.  So, you want

```
<% String abc = "1"; %>
....some stuff....
<% abc = "2"; %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
<%= abc = "2"; %>
```

To

```
<% abc = "2"; %>
```

Delete the "="

Answer (score 0):

A JSP expression is used to insert Java values directly into the output. It has the following form:

```
 &lt;%= Java Expression %&gt;
```

refer: http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-JSP.html

Using only one `=` operator to change value of abc.
http://faculty.cs.wwu.edu/meehan/Programming_Language_Projects/JSP/